# Exchange of order of integration in Gaussian integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gaussian-integral

I found this identity in an old book on integration, given without any explanation:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ze^{-z^2/2}dz\int_{-\infty}^{z} e^{-x^2/2}dx = 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2/2}dx \int_{-x}^{\infty}z e^{-z^2/2}dz 
$$
It may be trivial, so the question might be much easier than I imagined, but I really cannot see any jutification for this step.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**edit** Apparently, the problem was a typo in the last integral, that preventd me to see how the integration was to be carried over. The last integral should be

$$
\int_{x}^{\infty}z e^{-z^2/2}dz
$$
and then the equality is easily established via the Fubini theorem.

Comment: Hint. Draw a picture of the domain of integration.

Comment: The bound of integration is $$\{(x,z)\in \mathbb R^2\mid x<z\}.$$So, by Fubini theorem  $$\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{-\infty }^zdxdz=\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{x}^\infty dzdx.$$

Comment: @Surb Is it a typo in your second integral? Because in the text the second integral has $-x$, not $x$.

Comment: @RandomGuy: No, it should be $x$.

Comment: @Surb exactly, so the text must have a typo here.

Answer (score 1):

The region over which we are integrating is the half of the first quadrant bounded by the lines $x=0$ and $y=x$. Therefore the integrand is a nonnegative function, so Tonelli's theorem applies and the iterated integrals are equal. But it is a good exercise to actually sketch this region, as this often is an effective method of determining the new limits of integration when interchanging the order.